# Twitter Bootstrap - Tabs not working properly when tab content is long

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                    <p>a</p>
                    <p>very</p>
                    <p>long</p>
                    <p>content</p>
                    <p>string</p>
                    <p>to</p>
                    <p>simulate</p>
                    <p>very</p>
                    <p>long</p>
                    <p>paragraphs</p>
                    <p>for</p>
                    <p>testing</p>
                    <p>purposes</p>
                    <p>only</p>
                    <p>thank</p>
                    <p>you</p>
                    <p>and</p>
                    <p>good</p>
                    <p>morning</p>
                    <p>to</p>
                    <p>you</p>
                    <p>foo</p>
                    <p>bar</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
                   Profile Content Here
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
                    Messages Content Here
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">
                    Settings Content Here
                </div>
            </div>
```

Javascript

```
if (location.hash !== '')
    {
        $('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]').tab('show');
    }

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function(e) {
          return location.hash = $(e.target).attr('href').substr(1);
    });

    $(window).on("hashchange", function(){
        $('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]').tab('show');
    });​
```

I have code and demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nVU3r/)

Tabs is working fine when clicking on the other tabs other than #home. However, if I click on a tab with long content that is more than a page, the page focuses on the div which causes the  the viewport to home in on the respective div. Aesthetically, I would prefer that the page don't home in to that div.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `focus()` call to the shown event handler before it returns.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function(e) {
    location.hash = $(e.target).attr('href').substr(1);
    $(this).focus();
    return false; // or true - whichever you prefer
});
```

see the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nVU3r/3/

Updated the fiddle.  I have added `$()` around the element to permit focus call.  When settings the `location.hash` the browser automatically moves to the element.  We simply switch it back.

If you don't need the `location.hash` then you can remove the entire this entire code block and newly presented tab wont get focused.

Comment: I got TypeError: e.focus is not a function

Comment: Updated the answer - Do you need `location.hash` ? if you do not remove the entire handler and you will get the default behaviour - which is what you are asking for.

Comment: Yes. Because I want tab history.